# Erro Angular NG Serve

Tags: angular

Alguém sabe porque esta ocorrendo este erro?

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\cms\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:434:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:339:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:115:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:38:54)
    at Promise (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:92:49)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at scripts.map.fullPath (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:91:24)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at hook (C:\cms\Royal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:90:43)
```

Comment: João, faz o seguinte, deleta sua pasta "node_modules" e depois roda o comando npm install, isso deve resolver.

Comment: Fiz este procedimento e não deu certo.

Comment: João, tenta além de deletar a pasta node_modules executar o comando "npm cache clean --force" e depois fazer o "npm install" sempre executando o terminal no modo Admin.

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar agora.

Comment: @Giovanni Dias apareceu este novo erro

Comment: @JoãoRobertoVelozo esse erro começou quando?

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com esse mesmo problema apenas quando instalava o *jquery* no projeto. Sendo assim, para resolver o problema você deverá instalar o *jquery* caso tenha desinstalado.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

e depois vá no arquivo *angular.json* setar onde está a pasta de instalação do jquery.
Lá você deverá adicionar nos *scripts* a seguinte linha sem o `../` na frente da linha de código. Veja:

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
```

E também instalei o Tether com o comando:

```
npm install tether
```

Dentro do diretório do projeto.

Answer (score -1):

Realmente era a falta do Jquery :

```
npm install jquery --save
```