# Erro Node Ao Instalar o Bootstrap e Jquery

Tags: node.js

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\cms\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:115:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:38:54)
    at Promise (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:92:49)
    at new Promise ()
    at scripts.map.fullPath (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:91:24)
    at Array.map ()
    at hook (C:\cms\Fontenele\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:90:43)

Answer (score 0):

Eu respondi uma pergunta igual a tua em outro tópico, vai lá e se te ajudar, dá um like.

Segue o link --> [Error after installing of jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/346909/132691)